# Force update in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

What is the difference between a **force update** and a **normal update** in PhpStorm?

And is it bad when I use the force update mode?

Comment: In regards to updates to the IDE itself?

Comment: yes in regards to updates to the IDE itself

Answer (score 0):

Force update will check manually for an update to the IDE as it becomes avaliable. Jetbrains will typically wait a while before pushing notifications down to the platform. Won't do you any harm as the force update releases are typically very stable anyway